# VMware vSwitches and spanning tree

Tags: networking, vmware-esx

I have two redundant core switches I want to connect to a new vSwitch I am setting up on a VMware ESX host.  The switch will have two physical NICs each of which will connect to one of the core switches.  The core switches are connected.

If this was a physical switch, I would worry about connecting it to both core switches, because this would create a network loop.

Do I need to worry about this for a VMware virtual switch?  [VMware's documentation](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/virtual_networking_concepts.pdf) says it is not possible to connect two vSwitches in a loop, therefore STP is not required.  However, I am worried about connecting two physical switches together via a vSwitch.

Comment: We're doing the same thing you are trying to do and it works without a hitch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

vSphere doesn't forward packets like a switch does, so it cannot create a loop (unless a VM on that vSwitch forwards them). I have many vSphere hosts connected to two stacked Cisco switches and it works fine (both with some form of etherchannel and built-in VMWare failover).

Comment: Do you have spanning tree disabled for the ports, or are you using portfast and bpduguard disable on these ports instead?  I have Dell PowerConnect switches, which don't suppport disabling bpdu-guard at the port level (can only do globally).

Comment: I have STP portfast enabled on these ports.